# Action support on html table

Tags: apex, visualforce, html, actionsupport, table

I have a simple html table. I want another table2 to be showed only when I mouse hover on that table1 row. How to use Action support.

Please help below is my code,

Can you please help me out with my code. Below is my code..

```
apex:outputpanel >
       <apex:actionSupport event="onmouseover" action="{!showSupplier}" rerender="SD1" status="counterStatus">
          <table width="100%">
             <tr>
                <td width="50%">
                    First Table
                </td>
             </tr>
          </table>
       </apex:actionSupport>
     <apex:actionSupport event="onmouseout" action="{!hideSupplier}"/>
    </apex:outputpanel>
    <apex:outputPanel id="SD1"  >
        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!showSup}">
       <table width="100%" border="0" >
          <tr>
             <th  style="background-color:#e3e3d7;"> <b>Supplier Description </b></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td >
                Second Table
             </td>
          </tr>
       </table>
    </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:actionStatus startText=" (incrementing...)" stopText=" (done)" id="counterStatus"/>

</apex:form>
```

ShowSupplier is a method in which I'm setting a boolean value to TRUE. AND in Constructor is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

Small change whenever you are using rerender never use same element for rendered attribute. It will always refresh the below elemnts.

like this

```
<apex:page controller="HidePanelCtrl">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:outputpanel >
           <apex:actionSupport event="onmouseover" action="{!showSupplier}" rerender="SD1" status="counterStatus">
              <table width="100%">
                 <tr>
                    <td width="50%">
                        First Table
                    </td>
                 </tr>
              </table>
           </apex:actionSupport>
        </apex:outputpanel>
        <apex:outputPanel id="SD1"  >
            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!showSup}">
           <table width="100%" border="0" >
              <tr>
                 <th  style="background-color:#e3e3d7;"> <b>Supplier Description </b></th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td >
                    Second Table
                 </td>
              </tr>
           </table>
        </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        <apex:actionStatus startText=" (incrementing...)" stopText=" (done)" id="counterStatus"/>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

---

**Edit-2**

```
<apex:page controller="HidePanelCtrl">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:outputpanel >
       <apex:actionSupport event="onmouseover" action="{!showSupplier}" rerender="SD1" status="counterStatus">
          <table width="100%" border="1">
             <tr>
                <td width="50%">
                    First Table
                </td>
             </tr>
          </table>
       </apex:actionSupport>
     <apex:actionSupport event="onmouseout" action="{!hideSupplier}" rerender="SD1" status="counterStatus"/>
    </apex:outputpanel>
    <apex:outputPanel id="SD1"  >
        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!showSup}">
       <table width="100%"   border="1">
          <tr>
             <th  style="background-color:#e3e3d7;"> <b>Supplier Description </b></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td >
                Second Table
             </td>
          </tr>
       </table>
    </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:actionStatus startText=" (incrementing...)" stopText=" (done)" id="counterStatus"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I don't want to rerender table but rendered.. Initially table2 will be hidden but once I have mouse over the table1 it should display table 2 else it should be hidden.

Comment: wrapp your second table inside outputpanel with rerender attribte(intialliy set this to false) once you mouse over call a method there set the boolean value o true and rerender output panel... simple

Comment: Can you please help me out with my code. Below is my code..

Comment: @SfdcPro add your code in above question

Comment: Just added please check

Comment: @SfdcPro check my updated **Edit** Ans.

Comment: @SfdcPro let me know if this ans make sense to you ?

Comment: Yes..I'm implementing same thing in my code.. I'll let you know.

Comment: OMG...It worked...Reaaly Thank you.. But 1 thing is weird that table2 is not vanishing when i remove mouse cursor from table1. Any idea.??

Comment: you need one more action support for mouseout call a method there set the boolena to false and rerender

Comment: OK, Let me try. brb...

Comment: Hey I tried. It is working also. But I have put second actionSupport just after 1st actionSupport ends. Which ended with continuously rerendering the table.

Comment: Add your code in question let me check once.

Comment: Please check updated code

Comment: hey @SfdcPro your code working fine(Just added border in table so it will be clear where you are mouse overing and outing ). Its seems  continuously rerendering the table beacause you continusly doing mouseover and mouse out. I would suggest use on click first time click set true second time click set false

Comment: Is there any place, where I can put 2nd actionSupport in that outputpanel.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33091/discussion-between-ratan-and-sfdcpro).